# primeng - on page load show the multiselect dropdown?

Tags: angular, primeng

I am trying to display the dropdown of the multiselect on page load. With the current scenario if the user clicks on the dropdown icon the list will be displayed. But I am trying to display the list on page load itself.

```
    <p-multiSelect [showHeader]="false" [options]="stateOptions" placeholder="Exclude">
    </p-multiSelect>
```

I tried to implement the given method but not working.. How do I implement this method in primeng multiselect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the code below :-

```
<p-multiSelect [showHeader]="false" [options]="stateOptions" placeholder="Exclude" [overlayVisible]="true"> </p-multiSelect>
```